# Create a div that takes all the space between two others

Tags: css, html

I have two div elements. The one is on the very left and the other one ver right (same horizontal level).
Is it possible to create a thrid div that takes the whole space between the first and the second one without overlapping into them?

Here are my two div containers:

```
<div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
<div style="float:right; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tfYS5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?  The effect is acheived by creating a containing div that both the left and right floating divs will sit in.  Then a third div will contain any content needed without overflowing into the next ones

http://jsfiddle.net/tfYS5/5/

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftDiv"></div>
    <div class="content">Testing 123</div>
    <div class="rightDiv"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container{
    position:relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height:100px; 
    background-color:blue;
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.leftDiv{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px;
    width:100px;
    height:100%; 
    background-color:black;
}

.content{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    //the margin here should be the same as the width of the leftDiv & rightDiv   
    margin: 0px 100px;
}

.rightDiv{
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px;
    width:100px; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Edit: This is exactly what I was looking for. Answer accepted. Good job. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You should use the widht as the percent. So as an example;

```
<div id="1" style="width:30% "></div>
<div id="2" style="width:40% "></div>
<div id="3" style="width:30% "></div>
```

This should help and it will also accommodate the screen width this way.

ok then try using margin:auto instead of setting the width. OR even smarter. You can just set the position right? Left:100px, Right:100px since they are fixed.

Comment: But the div container on the very left and right must have a fixed size that doesn't change.. :/

Comment: ok then try using margin:auto instead of setting the width. OR even smarter. You can just set the position right? Left:100px, Right:100px since they are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to nesting the two div's within a parent div this could be a solution:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/tfYS5/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="remaining">
  <div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>  
  <div style="float:right; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.remaining{width:100%;height:100px;background-color:green;}
```

Comment: But the thrid div is overlapping (I should better say underlapping) the other two divs completely in this example. Isn't it? :/

Answer (score 0):

Taking as base your code:

```
 <div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
    <div style="float:right; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
    <div style="width:auto; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: The div is overlapping the other ones... :/

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`<div style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:blue;"></div>`
Under your existing code.

Comment: But the div would overlap the other ones then... :/